# jQuery BlockUI() unblocks before transferred to another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This issue is starting to puzzle me. Problem simply is that the jQuery's BlockUI() unblocks before the page is transferred to the next page.

In my ASP .NET application, on a client click event of a button on a user control I have the code below

```
  function btn_Click(){
        if(typeOf(Page_ClientValidate) = 'function'){
            Page.ClientValidate();
        }
        if(PageIsValid){
            BlockUI();//this is a wrapper for $.blockUI() with our custom css and message
        }
    }
```

Whenever the button is clicked after valid input, this code does executes and blocks the UI, but the BlockUI disappears before the page has been loaded with a new user control allowing user to re-click the button. To make it more interesting, I have the same piece of code doing what's expected on another user control's button's click event, exact copy paste of the same code. I have tried comparing every details I could think of with that user control, but there really isn't much to compare. I do not want to settimeout for $.unblock() because it would not be possible to tell how long it would take for the next user control to load and that surely isn't the right way. I did look up the $.blockUI() documentation and it don't seem to have any setting to tell it to wait until the post back is complete, that seems to be a default considering it works perfectly on couple other user controls. Any advice/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is the button causing a postback? Is your Javascript disappearing after the postback?

Comment: Yes, the button is causing a postback. I am not sure what you mean by 'Javascript disappearing,' but when I click the button, I will have the blockUI's css blocking the screen, just not long enough.